# Multiple conditions in sumif criteria

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, sumifs

The following formula works, but I'd like to simplify it:
`=SUMIFS(Availability!D:D,Availability!C:C,A6,Availability!B:B,"FE")+SUMIFS(Availability!D:D,Availability!C:C,A6,Availability!B:B,"BE")+SUMIFS(Availability!D:D,Availability!C:C,A6,Availability!B:B,"QA")`

I would expect the following to work, but I only get the total of FE. I want Availability!B:B to return when it's either FE BE or QA.
`=SUMIFS(Availability!D:D,Availability!C:C,A6,Availability!B:B,{"FE","BE","QA"})`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query instead

```
=SUM(QUERY(Availability!A:D,"select D where C='"&A6&"'and B matches'(FE|BE|QA)'"))
```

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is there any way to expand the selection to Availability!A:AW, and have "select D" change to "select E" etc as I copy the formula to adjacent columns?